# Implementing unary subtraction, negation, minus operator, "operator-" in class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, unary-operator

I am looking into implementing the unary 'negation', 'sign-inversion' or 'subtraction' operator, probably as a friend function to my class.

My guess at the correct way to do this is:

```
namespace LOTS_OF_MONNIES_OH_YEAH { // sorry, couldn’t resist using this namespace name

    class cents
    {

    public:
        cents(const int _init_cents)
            : m_cents(_init_cents)
        {
        }


    public:
        friend inline cents operator-(const cents& _cents);

    private:
        int m_cents;

    };


    inline cents operator-(const cents& _cents)
    {
        return cents(-(_cents.m_cents));
    }

}
```

Is my guess correct?

PS: Ideally namespace names should be in lower case as upper case is often used exclusively for constants, however I thought upper case provided more impact.

PPS: Ripped the example from [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/92-overloading-the-arithmetic-operators/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading :)

Comment: @melak47 Thanks, that also provides a lot of useful info, but not specifically about the unary `operator-`, still thanks anyway I will be using that in a minute! (Turns out I guessed correctly anyhow) (:

Answer (score 1):

The unary operator takes exactly one argument (hence the *unary*). If you want to implement it as non-member function you could define it like this:

```
inline cents operator-(cents const& value)
{
    return cents(-value.m_cents);
}
```

Of course, the signature of the `friend` declaration needs to match the definition.

Comment: @EdwardBird: so what's your question then...?

Comment: Asking to confirm if I was correct in my guess. I suspected I had missed something, but looks like I got it right first (second) time? Often it is as well to ask a question if unsure. Question hasn't been asked before as far as the search results could tell me.

Comment: @EdwardBird: OK, fair enough. BTW, just for the fun of it: you can also define unary plus: `inline cents operator+(cents value) { return value; }` It is rarely particular useful but for completeness...

Comment: Yeah good idea - seems like a good idea to implement both. I assume without the `operator+`, the compiler will complain if I tried to do something like: `cents c1(10); cents c2(12); c1 = +c2` ?

Comment: @EdwardBird: yes, this is correct. However, it is rare that expressions like this are used.